# push as object, or as separated items

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, ecmascript-6

I have very simple question.

But what is the difference between:

```
export const addToCart = function(product, quantity){
    cart.push({product, quantity});
    console.log(`${quantity} ${product} are added`);
}
```

and

```
export const addToCart = function(product, quantity){
    cart.push(product, quantity);
    console.log(`${quantity} ${product} are added`);
}
```

Thank you

Comment: console.log(cart) to see difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First is push an object into an array while second is push each item into an array.

```
var a =[];
a.push({b:1,c:2}) // [{b: 1, c: 2}]
a.push(1,2) // [1,2]
```

Comment: Oke, but what is the benefit of it? If you push it as an object?

Comment: Since your data structure is a field of string and a field of int, it would be recommand to push it as an object. You can then operate it by many fumction such as filter by name.

Answer (score 1):

In this case:

```
cart.push({product, quantity})
```

is equals to

```
cart.push({ product: product, quantity: quantity})
```

This [Shorthand property names](http://Shorthand%20property%20names) was introduced in [ES2015/es6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript#6th_Edition_%E2%80%93_ECMAScript_2015).
When there is a property name that is same as a variable name (a variable that contains your property value), you do not need to mention the property name while initializing the object.

So in your case, you are adding an object with properties `property` and `quantity` into a `cart` array.
So when you console log you will see like `[{'property': 'bottle', 'quantity': 99 }]`

In this case:

```
cart.push(product, quantity);
```

you are normally adding two items whose value is in `product` and `quantity` variables. So when you console log you will see something like `['bottle', 99 ]`

```js
cart = [];
//cart = [];
const addToCart = function(product, quantity){
    cart.push({product, quantity});
    console.log(cart);
}

const addToCart2 = function(product, quantity){
    cart.push(product, quantity);
    console.log(cart);
}

addToCart("product 1", 100); // [ { "product": "product 1", "quantity": 100 }]
//addToCart2("product 1", 100); // [  "product 1", 100 ]
```